# Tag proposal: perfect-numbers

Tags: discussion, tagging

There are quite many questions involving [perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number). Both even and odd perfect numbers are interesting in their own right, and then there are also numbers that are almost perfect, quasiperfect, multiply perfect, hemiperfect, hyperperfect, superperfect, unitary perfect, semiperfect etc. In addition, this tag [already exists on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/perfect-numbers). I think it would be useful to have this tag on MSE as well.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me

Comment: See [Should every new tag be discussed on meta before creation?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17023)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tag [perfect-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perfect-numbers) exists. It has 68 tagged questions since its creation in August, 2014.

Comment: Interesting! I guess have nothing more to add.

Comment: @Anonymous How on Earth did you not think of checking if the tag already existed...?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I have no idea. I remember that it didn't exist two years ago, and then I found it on MathOverflow.